# Retrofit: Making Web Requests to Internal APIs

Tags: java, android

I want to make a request to my organisation api's. The request contains Headers, UserName, Password, & Cookie for session management.

Below is the actual code (in HttpClient) which I want to rewrite using Retrofit. I have heard that HttpClient libraries have been deprecated or someting so have opted Retrofit. I expect the response with 200 status code.

```
    public static CookieStore cookingStore = new BasicCookieStore();
public static HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
public String getAuth(String login,String password) {
    String resp = null;
    try {
        String url = DOMAIN+"myxyzapi/myanything";
        context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookingStore);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        String log = URLEncoder.encode(login, "UTF-8");
        String pass = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        String json = "username="+log+"&password="+pass+"&maintain=true&finish=Go";
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        post.setEntity(entity); 
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,context);
        resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        accountPoller();
    } catch(Exception a) {
        log.info("Exception in authentication api:"+a.getMessage().toString());
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Below is my code where I can't figure out how to pass the **context** with **request**. `HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,**context**);` using retrofit.
I don't even know if I have made my retrofit request right.

```
try {

        String log = URLEncoder.encode(login, "UTF-8");
        String pass = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("username=", xyz)
                .add("password=", mypass)
                .add("&maintain=", "true")
                .add("finish=", "Go")
                .build();


        String url = www.xyz.com+"myxyzapi/myanything";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(formBody).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myresp = response.body().string();

                }
            }
        });

    } catch(Exception a) {
        a.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid using overly descriptive titles. The edit to your title was OK: The second sentence should be something that is added as part of your question instead. A general rule of thumb is that if your title needs to be broken into two or more sentences, it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch exception and use this class.
retrofit2.HttpException

retrofit2
Class HttpException

int
code() 
HTTP status code.
String
message() 
HTTP status message.
Response
response() 
The full HTTP response.

Comment: the problem is that it is not returning 200 success code. Can you help me achieve that.

Comment: you have to send  me  full code with credentials..If you can make it in postman and send me screenshot of  all what is added  to request . I can convert it to retrofit .

Comment: thanks for timely responses. Anyways the problem has been solved now. Just made some silly mistakes.